# Linking up the SQLite database with Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

I am using Tiatanium and SQLite Manager for firefox... I dont know how to linkup the Database in Titanium. Please help me... Thanks

Comment: please give some more information on what you are trying to achieve, and what you have tried

Comment: I downloaded extension for firefox SQLite manager 0.7.7 and want to create the tables in the database and insert the values into them using Titanium Javascript ......

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is creating database in titanium and using it. You just have to do some think like this,

```
Titanium.Database.open("Your database name");
```

It will create your database file. Than you can fire any query on that database using titanium database API. Whether to create table, select, insert, update etc....

Than to open that database in your SQLite manager. If you using android than you can find your database file in DDMS's file explorer and for iPhone you can find in applicationsupport/iphonesimulator/version ....

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this documentation. Just include the SQLite file in your `Resources` Directory

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Database-module

Note that Android sometimes has some problems with big database files, if you just rename it to something like `database.mp3` it suddenly does accept it.